# Separation of concerns

Tags: domain-driven-design, modeling, separation-of-concerns

I'm approaching the DDD way and I was posing myself some questions. Assume that I'm writing an application that lets you define a nutritional week, where you can

- Define a nutritional week as a resource having a list of aliment to eat for each of the 7 days
- Activate/deactivate the created weeks in a sort of calendar

My idea was to have two bounded contexts: the `Nutrition` and the `Progress` bounded contexts. The `Nutrition` BC is responsible of creating the nutritional weeks (similar as a portfolio), while the `Progress` bounded context is responsible of tracking the user nutrition.

Inside these two BC, I will have a `NutritionWeek` aggregate and in the `Progress` BC a `PlanWeek` aggregate. Now, I have some doubts on where the activate/deactivate functionalities should resides. I was thinking that these should be on the `NutritionWeek` aggregate: when the user activate a `NutritionWeek` it will call a domain service which will check if a `NutritionWeek` is already active, if yes -> exception, if not -> an event `NutritionWeekActivated` will be fired. In this event the `NutritionWeek` essential information is reported and the `PlanWeek` aggregate will handle this event by creating 7 `PlanDays` value objects, containing the aliments specified in the `NutritionWeek`. When a `NutritionWeek` is updated and is currently active, a `NutritionWeekUpdated` event is fired and the `PlanWeek` will handle the event by updating its `PlanDays`.

In general, I think that the `PlanWeek` should only be responsible of tracking the `User` nutrition. On the other hand, the `NutritionWeek` responsibility is to tell to the `PlanWeek` how to create its `PlanDays`.

P.S: at the moment I'm not planning to use events, so the integration between these two BC will be done as Open Host and Http/Rest. So, there would be an application service in the `Nutrition` BC that will activate the `NutritionWeek` and then call the `Progress` BC via HTTP.

What do you think?

Comment: I think you’re over complicating it with two bounded contexts. This seems to me very much like a single BC.

Comment: Hi, you are right, they should be in the same BC, but still two separate aggregates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Evans, a bounded context is :

> The delimited applicability of a particular model. Bounding contexts gives **team members** a clear and shared understanding of what has to be consistent and what ***can*** develop independently.

So separated bounded contexts imply a clean separation of concerns. But conversely, does separation of concerns necessarily need to shape the bounded context? Not necessarily.

If your nutrition and planning candidate-contexts are very complex, and each has different subject matter experts, use some different terms or terms differently, and if the complexity is so big that different teams will be involved, then go for different bounded context.

But from your narrative, this does not seem the case.  Don't artificially create bounded context, just to mirror the subdivision of your components. There is a slight **risk of over-engineering** here.

And fortunately, there are plenty of other means at our disposal for separating concerns, such as aggregates, services and even repositories (in their own way).  Bounded context is realy the steamroler in this regard, which in addition requires some overhead for coordination.  DDD is meant for helping you to get your domain right. Up to you to keep it as simple as possible ;-)